# Fatal error post.php help :(

Tags: posts, errors

I would really appreciate any help with my website that crashed and the following error appears

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /home1/zesiku/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 2160"

I have checked cpanel and see the following. The line that says `if ( 'readable' == $perm && is_user_logged_in() ) {` is the 2160. What to do :(((

```
function _count_posts_cache_key( $type = 'post', $perm = '' ) {
    $cache_key = 'posts-' . $type;
    if ( 'readable' == $perm && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $type );
        if ( $post_type_object && ! current_user_can( $post_type_object->cap->read_private_posts ) ) {
            $cache_key .= '_' . $perm . '_' . get_current_user_id();
        }
    }
    return $cache_key;
}
```

Comment: Have you modified WP core, and are you running the latest version of WordPress?

Comment: Can you check once by deactivating all WordPress plugins and activating WordPress default theme?

Comment: I am unable to open the website at all and the page gives a fatal error. So all i can do is stare at the cpanel and that is high level for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in `whatever` function:

```
function whatever(){
    // do stuff
}
add_action( 'init', 'whatever' );
```

Or use this to check whether user is logged in or not:

```
if( get_current_user_id() ) {
    // logged in user
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! can you please be specific where i need to paste these?

Comment: Hi, [Here you are](https://pastebin.com/5TNAPsm8)